error: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression
I have this code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

/* If either of the if-true or if-false expressions of ?: is void *, then the
 * of the result shall also be void * (plus const if either is const). */
#define TO_VOID_PTR(P)  (1 ? (P) : (void *)(P))

#define PTR_FMT(P)        \
    _Generic(TO_VOID_PTR(P), \
        void const *: "%p",  \
        void *      : "%p"   \
    )

/* Get the corresponding format specifier of a type. */
#define PRINTF_FMT(T)                                \
    _Generic((T),                                    \
                _Bool                   : "%d",      \
                char                    : "%c",      \
                signed char             : "%hhd",    \
                unsigned char           : "%hhu",    \
                short int               : "%hd",     \
                int                     : "%d",      \
                long int                : "%ld",     \
                long long int           : "%lld",    \
                unsigned short int      : "%hu",     \
                unsigned int            : "%u",      \
                unsigned long int       : "%lu",     \
                unsigned long long int  : "%llu",    \
                float                   : "%f",      \
                double                  : "%f",      \
                long double             : "%Lf",     \
                char *                  : "%s",      \
                wchar_t *               : "%ls",     \
                default                 : PTR_FMT(T) \
    )


#define print(x)    printf(PRINTF_FMT(x), x)

/* A separate call to putchar() is required because _Generic is not a macro, but
 * a primary expression. As such it is evaluated at a later translation phase (7)
 * than string concatenation (phase 6). */
#define println(x)  printf(PRINTF_FMT(x), x), putchar('\n')

int main(void)
{
    println("hello");
    println(10);
    println(5u);
    println('A');   
}

Compiling with GCC 14.1 with the following flags -std=c23 -O3 -Werror -Wall -Wextra resulted in these error messages:
<source>:48:5: error: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression ('int' and 'void *') [-Werror,-Wconditional-type-mismatch]
   48 |     println(10);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:43:28: note: expanded from macro 'println'
   43 | #define println(x)  printf(PRINTF_FMT(x), x), putchar('\n')
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:34:43: note: expanded from macro 'PRINTF_FMT'
   34 |                 default                 : PTR_FMT(T) \
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:14: note: expanded from macro 'PTR_FMT'
    9 |     _Generic(TO_VOID_PTR(P), \
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:28: note: expanded from macro 'TO_VOID_PTR'
    6 | #define TO_VOID_PTR(P)  (1 ? (P) : (void *)(P))
      |                            ^ ~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:49:5: error: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression ('unsigned int' and 'void *') [-Werror,-Wconditional-type-mismatch]
   49 |     println(5u);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:43:28: note: expanded from macro 'println'
   43 | #define println(x)  printf(PRINTF_FMT(x), x), putchar('\n')
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:34:43: note: expanded from macro 'PRINTF_FMT'
   34 |                 default                 : PTR_FMT(T) \
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:14: note: expanded from macro 'PTR_FMT'
    9 |     _Generic(TO_VOID_PTR(P), \
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:28: note: expanded from macro 'TO_VOID_PTR'
    6 | #define TO_VOID_PTR(P)  (1 ? (P) : (void *)(P))
      |                            ^ ~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:50:5: error: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression ('int' and 'void *') [-Werror,-Wconditional-type-mismatch]
   50 |     println('A');   
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:43:28: note: expanded from macro 'println'
   43 | #define println(x)  printf(PRINTF_FMT(x), x), putchar('\n')
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:34:43: note: expanded from macro 'PRINTF_FMT'
   34 |                 default                 : PTR_FMT(T) \
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:14: note: expanded from macro 'PTR_FMT'
    9 |     _Generic(TO_VOID_PTR(P), \
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:28: note: expanded from macro 'TO_VOID_PTR'
    6 | #define TO_VOID_PTR(P)  (1 ? (P) : (void *)(P))
      |                            ^ ~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~

Why is _Generic choosing the default case for 10, 5u, and 'A' when separate cases for int and unsigned int are present?

How do you figure your TO_VOID_PTR(P) should ever evaluate to something other than P given that 1 is always true?

@DevSolar "The macro TO_VOID_PTR seems strange since 1 always evaluates to true so the result is always (P). That may seem pointless, but we want the side-effect of the ?: operator which is: 'If either of the if-true or if-false expressions of ?: is void*, then the type of the result shall also be void* (plus const if either is const).'
Since we’ve explicitly cast P to void* for the if-false expression, that forces the type of the result also to be void* (or void const*) regardless of the pointer type." - From https://dev.to/pauljlucas/generic-in-c-i48

@dbush already has the answer while I was still debugging things. What I did first was reducting your example to the bare minimum that would be necessary to prove your assumption that _Generic was picking the wrong case -- just one macro mapping int to "int" and default to "other", and puts( MACRO( 5 ) ) -- which printed int, so _Generic is not picking wrongly. Only by adding your TO_VOID_PTR construct to the default case resulted in the error you described, and... well, by that time dbush had already written the answer. Showcasing the importance of a MINIMAL example...

...as reducing the example code to the actual bare minimum, i.e. dropping all the pretense of doing anything productive other than showcasing the error, in my experience, resolves the error in 80%+ of all cases. If it doesn't, you have an example that clearly exposes the issue, and will not get discussed on what it does or does not do, whether it's good design to do it that way, etc. ;-)

@DevSolar From the output, I obviously could tell that _Generic was working just fine. It is only that I found the error messages inexplicable.

Aside: Consider "%g" rather than "%f" for FP types.  Better output over the wide range of values. (Even better, incorporate a precision other than rely on default 6.)

The _Generic expression isn't choosing the default case.  The issue is that all cases must be a valid expression.
This means that the conditional:
(1 ? (P) : (void *)(P))

Which for the second case is being evaluated as:
(1 ? (10) : (void *)(10))

Results in a conversion between an integer type and a pointer type between the second and third parts of the conditional, which is a constraint violation as per section 6.5.15p3 of the C standard regarding the conditional operator.
You can accomplish what you want by getting rid of the conditional and just casting to const void *, since you don't intent to change what the result points to.
#define TO_VOID_PTR(P)  ((const void *)(P))


Casting to void* misses the point of the macro as originally defined which is that the result should be void* if and only if the argument already is a pointer. The OP mis-used the macro in his example by passing a non-pointer to it via default. Perhaps I'll revise my article to mention the caveat. (FYI: while the OP is quoting my article, I'm not the originator of the ?: trick for void*.)

@PaulJ.Lucas I find the examples I typed down identical to the ones in your article, and fail to see how they differ, or how I have called PRINTF_FORMAT() incorrectly. Perhaps I am being silly, but would you like to explain, does your example not call PTR_FORMAT() similarly via default? How am I misusing the macro?

@Harith I was confused by the error since I know my code didn't generate an error, but now see you added -Werror. If you remove that, the code merely warns, so the code works. You can choose to suppress that warning. So I thought you must have misused it. Sorry.

@PaulJ.Lucas It looks like you'll get an actual error if you pass in a floating point value, as there's no conversions allowed between pointer types and floating point types.  An intermediate cast to uintptr_t won't help because out-of-range conversions between integer and floating point types is UB.

You are correct. For println(10.3), I received: "error: cannot convert to a pointer type". And that was without any warnings enabled.
